# Invertible skew-symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, skew-symmetric-matrices

I'm working on a proof right now, and the question asks about an invertible skew-symmetric matrix. How is that possible? Isn't the diagonal of a skew-symmetric matrix always $0$, making the determinant $0$ and therefore the matrix *is not* invertible?

Comment: Having vanishing diagonal entries means the trace is always zero, but the *determinant* need not necessarily be zero. Consider $\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: To jump a bit forward: odd-order skew-symmetric matrices are necessarily singular, but even-order ones don't have to be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The diagonal of a skew-symmetric matrix is always $0$ does not mean that its determinant be $0$. Look at following example:

$det\left[ \begin{array}{}
   0 & 1 \\
   -1 & 0 \\
  \end{array}  \right]=1
$

Its inverse is:
$\left[ \begin{array}{}
   0 & -1 \\
   1 & 0 \\
  \end{array}  \right]
$

Answer (score 9):

No, the diagonal being zero does not mean the matrix must be non-invertible. Consider $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \\ \end{pmatrix}$. This matrix is skew-symmetric with determinant $1$. 
 Edit: as a brilliant comment pointed out, it *is* the case that if the matrix is of odd order, then skew-symmetric will imply singular. This is because if $A$ is an $n \times n$ skew-symmetric we have $\det(A)=\det(A^T)=det(-A)=(-1)^n\det(A)$. Hence in the instance when $n$ is odd, $\det(A)=-\det(A)$; over $\mathbb{R}$ this implies $\det(A)=0$.